# Google DataStore - how to fetch data by date

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to write a fetch query for DataStore.

In datastore it has date field column with this format **2018-02-20 (11:07:36.000) MMT**

I want to fetch only data of the specified date

I'm doing the following but it's not working:

```
def query(self, date=None):

    query = self.client.query(kind='Test')
    if date != None:
        query.add_filter('date', '>', datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        query.add_filter('date', '<', datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

    results = list(query.fetch())
    print(results)

    return results


if __name__ == '__main__':
    date = 20181012
    data_list = query(date)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Side note: your `date` is an integer, passing it to `datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')` won't work, you'll get a `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not int`. You'd need to use a string, not an int. But that's not really the problem.

> In datastore it has date field column with this format **2018-02-20
>   (11:07:36.000) MMT**

The format is irrelevant, you shouldn't operate with timestamp properties as strings. In other words you shouldn't needs to use `strftime/strptime`. You should deal with them as `datetime` objects instead. You can find an example in [Restrictions on queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#restrictions_on_queries):

> ```
> start_date = datetime.datetime(1990, 1, 1)
> end_date = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
> query = client.query(kind='Task')
> query.add_filter(
>     'created', '>', start_date)
> query.add_filter(
>     'created', '<', end_date)
> ```

Another important note is that your query with the filters added will never produce any result: no `'date'` property value can simultaneously be both greater than and smaller than **the same** other value  - your `datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`, present in both filters. You need to provide 2 **different** start and end timestamp values in the 2 filters.

Adapting the above example for your question it'd be something like:

```
    query.add_filter('date', '>=', date)
    query.add_filter('date', '<', date + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

and you'd specify `'date'` as a `datetime`:

```
date = datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing a Date equality filtering via JDO Queries in GAE with JAVA Runtime:

```
public List<User> findByOrganizationIdAndDOB(Long organizationID, Date dateOfBirth) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    List<User> userList = null;
    try {

        Query q = pm.newQuery(User.class);
                q.declareImports("import java.util.Date");
                q.setFilter("organizationId ==organizationID && dateOfBirth==dateOfBirthParam");
                q.declareParameters("Long organizationID, Date dateOfBirthParam");
            
                userList = (List<User>) q.execute(organizationID,dateOfBirth);      
        
        return userList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }

}
```